# How to install opencv on windows

Tags: anaconda, conda, face-recognition

I want to install face_recognition package on windows using anaconda prompt, however the official documentation says, "Windows not officially supported, but might work".
I'm getting error of OpenCV(dlib) while trying to install face_recognition.
Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by the following commands:

1. Downgrade python for compatibility.

   > conda install python=3.6.0
2. Install dlib from conda-forge

   > conda install -c conda-forge dlib
3. Install face_recognition pkg with --no-dependencies flag to avoid installation of dlib as dependency

   > pip install --no-dependencies face_recognition